# How to enable the move gizmo via script?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, startup-file, gizmo

I created a new startup file+script for low-poly 3D modeling for my game project. Basically a default cube with origin on the "floor" and a custom material. The script sets up my preferred editor settings (inspired by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8) but there's just one problem...

I can't seem to enable the move gizmo from the startup script.

[image: move gizmo not getting enabled on startup]

Here's the code:

```py
import bpy

def setup_material():
    bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image.filepath_raw = "/home/gk/Desktop/gamedev/projects/shooter/textures/simple_palette.png"
    bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image.reload()

def setup_viewport():
    bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['UV Editing']
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    space.shading.type = 'SOLID'
                    space.shading.color_type = 'TEXTURE'
                    space.shading.show_backface_culling = True
                    space.shading.show_cavity = True
                    space.shading.cavity_type = 'BOTH'
                    space.shading.cavity_ridge_factor = 2.5
                    space.shading.cavity_valley_factor = 2.5
                    space.shading.show_shadows = True
                    space.show_gizmo = True
                    space.show_gizmo_tool = True
                    space.show_gizmo_context = True
                    space.show_gizmo_object_translate = True

def register():
    setup_material()
    setup_viewport()


def unregister():
    pass
```

How can I enable the move gizmo from the startup script? I'm trying every possible way of doing it, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**The actual solution for saving UI settings is to set them and save a startup file - File -> Defaults -> Save Startup File** however if one wanted to run a startup script changing the UI, one could enable Python Tooltips in the preferences to see what buttons in the UI do:

[image]

or change something and see logged commands in the Info editor:

[image]

It also seems that startup scripts have limited context when they run, so you need to put whatever code you want to run in an app handler so it runs after loading a file:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    space.shading.type = 'SOLID'
                    space.shading.color_type = 'TEXTURE'
                    space.shading.show_backface_culling = True
                    space.shading.show_cavity = True
                    space.shading.cavity_type = 'BOTH'
                    space.shading.cavity_ridge_factor = 2.5
                    space.shading.cavity_valley_factor = 2.5
                    space.shading.show_shadows = True
                    space.show_gizmo = True
                    space.show_gizmo_tool = True
                    space.show_gizmo_context = True
                    space.show_gizmo_object_translate = True


def register():    
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
        
def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(load_handler)
```

Comment: That's incredibly useful! Thanks!

Comment: Talking about incredibly useful stuff when scripting in Blender - you know about auto-complete(tab) functionality in the Python Console, right? It's also very helpful when you want to explore the API.

Comment: I did not know that autocomplete worked in the scripting tab, lol. I've been using the good old dir(object) to introspect and the Blender API docs :D

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys but the querent already has the solution in his code `space.show_gizmo_object_translate = True` which already works, so I'm confused if this post solved his problem? Nevertheless it presents some useful information for the OP and the community.

Comment: That's true, it's confusing. I missed it, but I did test it before posting the answer and it does work.

Comment: I mean, you obviously need to call the function `register()` at the end for it to actually work... and I don't call `setup_material()`, because I don't have the images, but else than that it seems to work from the script Editor.

Comment: OK, so I only tested it from the Script Editor, not as a startup script. I don't really use startup scripts and never looked into how they work, because I would just make myself add-ons if I need something to run, when I start Blender. I think it would be best to do the same here. But I hesitate to provide another answer because now I started to wonder why this is done in the first place. If one needs some sort of interface settings, why not just save them with startup file? That's File->Defaults-> Save Startup File. @gulagkulak, why do you need it to be a script?

Comment: If template system is used for workspace tabs, the scripts(here: `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\startup\bl_app_templates_system\`  ) always define a load_factory_startup_post handler. So it seems you need one in a startup script if you wish to do stuff after startup file is loaded. I'll update the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get gizmo settings to save into the startup file for the longest time, but then suddenly it worked and now I have the perfect startup file without any need for scripting. So, yeah, thank you for the effort :)